# Overriding nested class in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding, inner-classes

I have a base class with inner class like this

```py
import pandas as pd

book_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'title': [f'title{num}' for num in range(5)],
        'due date': pd.date_range(start='2021-07-26', periods=5, freq='D').to_list(),
        'status': ['delay', 'delay', 'return', 'good', 'good']
    })

class BaseBookInfo(object):
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.counter = self.Counter(df)
    class Counter(object):
        def __init__(self, df):
            self.df = df
            self.total = len(self.df)
            self.status = self.count_status()
        def count_status(self):
            return self.df['status'].value_counts()
```

.. and I made a child class with some overridings like this.

```py
class BooksBorrowed(BaseBookInfo):
    status_type = {
        'ZERO_BORROW': 'no borrowed books',
        'DELAY_EXIST': 'there are delayed books!!',
        'NO_PROBLEM': 'there is no problem!!',
    }
    def __init_(self, df):
        super().__init__(df)
        self.counter = self.Counter(df, self.status_type)
    class Counter(BaseBookInfo.Counter):
        def __init__(self, df, st_type):
            super().__init__(df)
            self.types = st_type
        def show_status(self):
            is_delayed = self.status['good'] != self.total
            if self.total:
                if is_delayed:
                    result = 'DELAY_EXIST'
                else:
                    result = 'NO_PROBLEM'
            else:
                result = 'ZERO_BORROW'
            print(f'{self.types[result]}')
```

When I tested `BooksBorrowed`, I got this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ....
  File "D:/repository/BillMaker/src/billmaker/scraper/test_stackoverflow.py", line 54, in <module>
    bb = BooksBorrowed(book_df)
  File "D:/repository/BillMaker/src/billmaker/scraper/test_stackoverflow.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.counter = self.Counter(df)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'st_type'
```

I expect that `super().__init__()` call from `Counter` class of child class will be connected to the base class's inner class but I was wrong.

Can you tell me what is the wrong idea in my case ?

I don't want to change the position of`BooksBorrowed.status_type` because it will be used in `BookBorrowed` also.

Updates:
I came to read [some book](https://livebook.manning.com/book/code-like-a-pro/chapter-8/22) about this subject after asking this question. I found my example looks very similar with the typical case of breaking the `Liskov substitution principle`. Besides , I came to know what is the `has a` relationship, which @simonCrowe already commented below. So I understand now that this is a better case for composition, not inheritance. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want the counter classes to be nested? A typical has-a relationship would just instantiate the desired counter class in the `__init__` method and this counter class could even be imported from a different module. You could also store a reference to the counter class on the book info class, and do `self.couter = self.counter_class(df, self.status_type)` in the `__init__` method; I think you'd get the expected inheritance behavior in this case.

Comment: This is because you are accessing `self.Counter`, which will **always be** `BooksBorrowed.Counter` when `self` is an instance of `BooksBorrowed`.

Comment: @SimonCrowe  BooKInfo class is made for collecting information from `book_df`.  I think this is the best place for counting something in `book_df`. The counter instances without inner class was in the `__init__` module originally as you said. But it became dirty with so many counter instances. The original `book_df` is more complex than this and has many counting issues. So I made a decision  to use inner class. But this is my first time to use inner class. So I am still confused.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know `BookBorrowed.__init__` calls `self.Counter`. But `BooksBorrowed.Counter` inherited  `BaseBookInfo.Counter` . I thought `super()` in `BookBorrowed.Counter` means `BaseBookInfo.Counter` . Am I wrong ?

Comment: *It never reaches `BookBorrewd.Counter`*. It goes `BookBorrowed.__init__`, then via `super().__init__(df)` you are in `BaseBookInfor.__init__`, where you call `self.Counter`, but `self` is an instance of `BookBorrowed`.  So first it checks the instance namespace, and it doesn't find `Counter`. Then it checks the class namespace, and finds `BookBorrowed.Counter`, and that is what it resolves to

Comment: @hong inner classes are not really something that are used often in Python,  and I'm not sure why you think it is appropriate in this case

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I finally understand what you are meaning and why it fails. I don't insist on using inner classes. It's only curiosity if I can use new type of solution. It looks like that inners classes are not popular solution. I need to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

(Below, I've retained the nested class structure. But notice that the classes themselves could just as easily be defined outside of the book classes, using any names you like, as long as the `Counter` class attribute is assigned the desired class.)

---

Separate the knowledge of how to instantiate the `Counter` class from `__init__` and put it into a class method instead.

```
class BaseBookInfo:
    class Counter:
        def __init__(self, *, df, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            self.df = df
            self.total = len(self.df)
            self.status = self.count_status()
        def count_status(self):
            return self.df['status'].value_counts()

    def __init__(self, *, counter, **kwargs):
        super.__init__(**kwargs)
        self.counter = counter

    @classmethod
    def from_dataframe(cls, df, **kwargs):
        c = cls.Counter(df=df, **kwargs)
        return cls(counter=c)
```

Now the caller is responsible for making sure `Counter` is instantiated correctly, either by doing it manually

```
b = BaseBookInfo(counter=BaseBookInfo.Counter(df))
```

or via the dedicated constructor

```
b = BaseBookInfo.from_dataframe(df=df)
```

When you subclass `BaseBookInfo`, you don't need to provide new definitions for either `__init__` or `from_dataframe`; they are already general enough to work with whatever class attribute `Counter` you define.

```
class BorrowedBook(BaseBookInfo):
    class Counter(BaseBookInfo.Counter):

        # These are Counter attributes, not BorrowedBook attributes
        ZERO_BORROW = 'no borrowed books'
        DELAY_EXIST = 'there are delayed books!!'
        NO_PROBLEM = 'there is no problem!!'
        
        def __init__(self, *, st_type, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            self.types = st_type

        def show_status(self):
            is_delayed = self.status['good'] != self.total
            if not self.total:
                result = self.ZERO_BORROW
            elif is_delayed:
                result = self.DELAY_EXIST
            else:
                result = self.NO_PROBLEM
            print(result)

bb1 = BorrowedBook(counter=BorrowedBook.Counter(df=df, st_type=stat))
bb2 = BorrowedBook.from_dataframe(df, st_type=stat)
```

In the case of `bb2`, `BorrowedBook` is the `cls` argument of the inherited `from_dataframe` class method, so the correct `Counter` is instantiated.

Comment: Your answer meets my original intention except the `BooksBorrowed.status_type` part. But I can not accept your answer.  I detected bad smell in my code but i couldn't find what's wrong. So I asked this question. (I asked "What is the wrong idea in my code?") But your answer strengthen bad part of my code. Now I learned that my code is breaking many rules about inheritance from the op's comments. Now I am trying to follow this rule.  `Use composition for has-a relationships`.

Comment: Are you referring to the nested class? I mentioned that at the top: you can define the `Counter` class outside of the book class, and the only thing you need to change is how you refer to `Counter` (`Counter` instead of `BaseBookInfo.Counter`, for example.) This also doesn't break any rules concerning composition: I moved the actual status types out of the book class and into the counter class, which is what defines the notion of having a status.

Comment: I am not pointing the nested class. I am pointing the way of inheritance. In your code, `BorrowedBook.Counter` inherited from `BaseBookInfo.Counter` and both classes have different instance creation signature. This part has two problems according to the book I referenced. The one is violation of substitutability, also known as `Liskov Substituion Principle`.  The other is  the way of superclass access.  I mentioned this part in my answer.  In your answer , this bad part is not corrected.  On the contrary, it looks like you are showing some other way that keeps my dangerous code growing.

Comment: You can *add* arguments to the signature, as long as any upstream classes are willing to ignore unrecognized argument beyond what they will pass on themselves. This is part of cooperative inheritance; you can read a longer description of the idea in https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/.

Answer (score 0):

I referenced [this book](https://www.manning.com/books/practices-of-the-python-pro) and I found that my code are breaking many rules of inheritance.
All the block-quoted part down below came from this book.

- The rules of inheritance I broke

  - Substitutability :

    > Using a different instance creation signature is a common way to violate `substitutability`.

    - In my code, `BooksBorrowed.Counter` is breaking the `substitutabiltiy`
  - Superclass access :

    > Overriding methods to take different numbers of arguments, and passing only some of them along using super(), can lead to confusion and poor maintainability.

    - In my code, `BooksBorrowed.Counter.__init__` is taking diferrent numbers of arguments.
  - `has-a` relationship

    > Use composition for has-a relationships

    - In my code, 'Counter' `has a` 'status-type'. But, `status-type` is overrided in the inheritance way.
- How to use the composition way.

  > Inversion of control says that instaed of creating instances of dependencies in your class, you can pass in existing instances for the clas to make use of.

  - There are two relations in my code. They are 'BaseBookInfo'- 'Counter' and 'Counter'-'status_type'
    They are tightly coupled each outher so it is hard to upgarde. They need to be coupled loosely.

This is my final code which I think better. If you find any part can be improved more, please answer my question, I will accept yours. I don't want to accept mine as final answer.

```py
class BaseCounter(object):
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
        self.total = len(self.df)
        self.status = self.count_status()
    def count_status(self):
        return self.df['status'].value_counts()

class BaseBookInfo(object):
    def __init__(self, df, counter):
        self.df = df
        self.counter = counter

bi = BaseBookInfo(book_df, BaseCounter(book_df))

class BBCounter(BaseCounter):
    def __init__(self, df):
        super().__init__(df)
        self.types = dict()
    def get_status_type(self, types):
        self.types = types
    def show_status(self):
        is_delayed = self.status['good'] != self.total
        if self.total:
            if is_delayed:
                result = 'DELAY_EXIST'
            else:
                result = 'NO_PROBLEM'
        else:
            result = 'ZERO_BORROW'
        print(f'{self.types[result]}')

class BooksBorrowed(BaseBookInfo):
    status_type = {
        'ZERO_BORROW': 'no borrowed books',
        'DELAY_EXIST': 'there are delayed books!!',
        'NO_PROBLEM': 'there is no problem!!'
    }
    def __init__(self, df, counter):
        super().__init__(df, counter)
        self.counter.get_status_type(self.status_type)

bb = BooksBorrowed(book_df, BBCounter(book_df))
```